# É possível levantar projetos de desktop no GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Será que posso desenvolver meus programas desktop e levantar para o GitHub, e trabalhar dessa forma com versionamento do meu programa com o Git?

Ou será que só posso levantar projetos web para o GitHub?

Comment: Explique melhor sua dúvida. O que seria "levantar"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O GitHub é apenas um repositório de projetos, ele não sabe em que linguagem foi escrito, que tecnologia usou, em que forma ou outras características seu projeto tem. Então é claro que pode por um projeto "desktop". Na verdade nem precisa ser um software, mesmo que ele seja mais adequado para isto.

Você se comunica com ele basicamente através do Git. Todos podem pegar os arquivos dele, criar um *fork* e pedir para mesclar alguma alteração que fizeram. Alguns podem mesclar de forma direta, você tem controle sobre isto. O Github é só um centralizador que serve como cópia do seu projeto e que permite outras pessoas acessá-lo de forma conveniente. Claro que ele possui algumas ferramentas extras para comunicar com os usuários/desenvolvedores do seu projeto, mas são funcionalidades secundárias.

<strike>A utilização gratuita exige que o projeto seja aberto. Se deseja mantê-lo fechado, deverá usar uma conta paga. Agora tem a possibilidade de alguns projetos privados livres.</strike>